# Custom Test Fixture for LCR meter

Tags: capacitor, measurement, testing, instrumentation, lcr

I've designed and built a custom test fixture (based on Keysight's 16047A) to be able to measure multiple pin capacitors.

When testing it to compare both fixtures (the custom and the original), I verify that surrounding the resonance frequency they differ.

Measured with the original test fixture and the custom test fixture, respectively:

[image]

[image]

For both measurements I've performed short and open corrections - at the custom test fixture, the short device was also custom.

What might be happening and how to mitigate it? Would it be some sort of ground loop error?

Comment: It might the useful if you post pics of both the original and custom test fixtures, and of the short device, along with some construction details. Otherwise, it's difficult to say.

Answer (score 0):

If the open/short corrections are preformed correctly then there shouldn't be a problem, it looks like the test fixture could be changing. Do an open, then short, then open then short and compare the open results together. Then compare the short results together. If they aren't the same after switching then there is a problem with the repeatability of your test fixture (could be mechanical).

The values are very small parasitics at high frequencies which probably correspond to nH, pF and mΩ.